# Faster serialization of `Serializable` objects

Tags: .net, serializable, binaryformatter, netdatacontractserializer

Our client/server app uses a `NetDataContractSerializer` to serialize arbitrary `Serializable` objects.

The output of `BinaryFormatter` would be somewhat smaller, performance [however](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2009/09/protobuf-net-vs-netdatacontractserializ.html) isn't really [better](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/07/10/comparing-the-performance-of-net-serializers.aspx).

Now smaller representations are possible (e.g. the outputs of `XmlSerializer` and `DataContractSerializer`, Json, Protocol Buffers, Thrift, etc.), that also happen to serialize and deserialize much faster.

However, in order to use those I'd have to go to every single one of the `Serializable` classes and add attributes and potentially change access levels of fields etc. Not only are these classes spread over many different internal projects, but our clients have their own dlls with `Serializable` classes which would have to be modified. In other words, a major undertaking.

Is there any other performance improvement, and potential size reduction (other than gzipping etc.), possible for `Serializable` objects?

Answer (score 0):

Many of those serializers do not require custom attributes - in fact some are specifically designed to recognize and work with `SerializableAttribute`. See, for example:

- [JSON.NET's documented support of `SerializableAttribute`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm)
- [protobuf-net's approach](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Attributes) allowing runtime configuration and also supporting `DataContractAttribute` (which more accurately defines the characteristics you'd want in a wire protocol anyways). You could certainly configure protobuf-net at runtime to do what you want.

Json.NET example:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{ 
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
};
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialized, settings);
```

**UPDATE:** You don't need to fork Json.NET to do the type instantiation. I'm using a custom `JsonConverter` as described in [this article](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2012/02/json-deserialization-with-jsonnet-class.html).

Comment: Quoting from your protobuf link: `Contract types

Protobuf-net expects contract types to be explicitly marked as such; types can be marked [ProtoContract], [DataContract] or [XmlType] for this purpose ([Serializable] is not required and is not used)`

Comment: That's what I said. Quoting also from the very first line of that protobuf project wiki page: "Note that in v2 everything can also be configured at runtime without needing to edit any types."

Comment: I could get Json.NET to work (and added an example to your answer), but in case of protobuf-net I a) seem to have to add every (non-protobuf-annotated) type manually before serializing b) specify the exact type when deserializing (not e.g. a common super interface/class) c) protobuf complains unless there is a parameterless constructor. I.e. it doesn't seem to work as a drop-in replacement for BinaryFormatter/NetDataContractSerializer.

Comment: Thanks for adding that. Yes, there are definitely limitations on what's possible. If you're looking for a drop-in replacement that performs better and doesn't have any significant change in behavior, I don't think you'll find one - there's a reason the performance engineers at Microsoft get paid well. :) I would say it's definitely worth considering the benefits of adding a `[DataContract]` annotation, because as I said `[Serializable]` is really not meant for wire transmission unless you're sure you want to tightly couple your client & server. `[DataContract]` will open up more options.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure `NetDataContractSerializer` and `Json.NET` are 100% equiv, but the former takes 1.5 times the time of the latter in tests with actual complicated nested objects that I did, which surprised me a bit, as MS can do a lot of 'unsafe' stuff internally that Json.NET cannot.

Comment: The Json.NET snippet is still not enough to make it serialize like `NetDataContractSerializer`. Depending on the constructor setup of your class, you'll run into `Unable to find a constructor to use for type 'xxx'. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute`, which can be fixed by either changing your class (something I'm trying to avoid as I'm not controlling all classes) or by [forking Json.NET](http://blog.halan.se/post/Deserializing-objects-with-non-default-constructors-in-JSON-NET.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion after checking out Lars Kemmann's suggestions: **There is no alternative to `NetDataContractSerializer`/`BinaryFormatter` that serializes and deserializes the in the same way.**

I played around with `Json.NET`, and it kind of works, but as is often the case, the devil is in the details (see also my comments to Lars' answer):

Testing with real life objects it turned out my deserialized objects aren't 100% equivalent to the original ones, stemming from fields in super classes that don't get serialized. At least that is what it seems after a cursory check.

`Protobuf-net` is not an option either, as you

1. have to register every (non-protobuf-annotated) type manually before serializing
2. have to specify the exact type when deserializing
3. it complains about classes that don't have a parameterless constructor